# Thread or Runnable when using Canvas and SurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, android-canvas, runnable

I am interested in creating a 2D drawing application for Android using touch input. I will be using a SurfaceView to accomplish this as it is the most efficient next to OpenGL, but for this application, it should now be an issue.

After reading the documentation and overview (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) of SurfaceView and Canvas drawing, it seems they recommend creating an inner class which extends Thread to handle the work for drawing.

This makes sense of course as to not lock up UI and offload the work to a secondary thread. However, I am unsure why they do not use an external class which extends *Thread*, or even better, why not use a *Runnable* that is external?

Is there a benefit to leaving this as an inner class? And is there a benefit to extending *Thread* as opposed to implementing *Runnable* for *Canvas* drawing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in their scenario they got one thing right and one thing wrong IMO:

1. The decision to make the thread class an inner class is ok, because that class is only required in that particular part of the code, so no need to expose it to the outside.
2. I don't really agree with extending `Thread`. The best practice is to implement `Runnable` and override the `run` method. This is because you can use that `Runnable` in several different ways, like starting a normal thread, queuing it up in a thread pool, etc. It also allows you to extend a different class if you need, since `Runnable` is just an interface.

Comment: So you think maybe an inner class which implements runnable as opposed to extending a Thread, then assigning that Runnable to a standard Thread object?

Comment: @Tom Pennetta: Exactly, that's how I would do it.